# Azure Application Insight: Custom data not recorded when Timestamp or StartTime is set

Tags: azure-application-insights

I found a strange issue while sending data using custom code. No data appeared in the browser until I figured out it had something to do with how I send it. If I manually set the StartTime or Timestamp of a Telemetry class the data never shows up.

In the code below, only the event with name "None" shows up. Widening the time range of the filter in the browser dashboard does not help.

Is it not possible to send historical data to application insights with a custom datetime stamp?

I need it because my telemtry data comes from a single server and is then persisted to multiple destinations like Application Insights, SQL server en blob storage for later processing.

```
var rt = new RequestTelemetry
{
    Name = "StartTime",
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
};
telemetry.TrackRequest(rt);

rt = new RequestTelemetry
{
    Name = "Timestamp",
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
};
telemetry.TrackRequest(rt);

rt = new RequestTelemetry
{
    Name = "Both",
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
};
telemetry.TrackRequest(rt);

rt = new RequestTelemetry
{
    Name = "None",
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
};
telemetry.TrackRequest(rt);
```

Comment: ApplicationInsights should accept data that is not older than 48 hours. We are investigating why 24h old data is not showing up in the portal. It looks like a problem in querying it and should be available in the Continuous Export.

Comment: if you use fiddler and watch them get sent, you might be getting responses from the server that would tell you if/why it might be rejecting them.  the 24h rejection ones (if there are) might be depending on your timestamp?  try using `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime()` to make sure you're not getting any dates in the future or more than 48 UTC?