# How to prevent losing telemetry pageView with Application Insight's Persistence Channel?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

when internet connection is available application insights for wpf application works fine and I am able to track page and events in azure portal but I want to know is it possible to store telemetry data somewhere in system when their is no internet connection and retrieve it when system is online and track those actions which I performed when their was no internet connection.

Comment: Hello, you can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721396/can-application-insights-be-used-off-line). It should be possible, but maybe difficult and have some limitations.

Comment: Can i get c# code for implementing persistance channel in wpf @IvanYang

Comment: It's should be possible, but I'm not familiar with wpf project, so you can create [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues) and ask for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Application Insights for Desktop Applications](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/08/08/application-insights-for-desktop-applications/), it has nice code examples of using **Application Insights** with desktop applications in general, and also how to work/use the **Persistence Channel**. Taken from mentioned link:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    config.InstrumentationKey = "954f17ff-47ee-4aa1-a03b-bf0b1a33dbaf";

    config.TelemetryChannel = new PersistenceChannel();
    config.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = Debugger.IsAttached;

    telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);
    telemetryClient.Context.User.Id = Environment.UserName;
    telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And then:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

...

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionTelemetry excTelemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    excTelemetry.SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Critical;
    excTelemetry.HandledAt = ExceptionHandledAt.Unhandled;

    telemetryClient.TrackException(excTelemetry);

    telemetryClient.Flush();
}
```

**Update**

To track page views, you can use one of **TelemetryClient**'s [TrackPageView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackpageview?view=azure-dotnet) overloads, for example:

```
telemetryClient.TrackPageView("MyPageName");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: can i get it for pageviews @Itay Podhajcer

Comment: But there is an bug in persistance channel.... the data is not collected due to network adapters. :)