# Microsoftapplicationinsight.dll be edited in such a way to use it offline posting data to cloud

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, wiki

Im working for offline posting data to cloud azure. So by editing the dll can i do it?? Is there any way to edit the dll??

Comment: Why would you, there are numerous extension points in the SDK you can use. You could create your own TelemetryChannel for example. But offline telemetry collection won't be easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Application Insights be used off-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721396/can-application-insights-be-used-off-line)

Comment: @PeterBons, I see you have answered a similar issue before, could you please give some detailed instructions about it?

Comment: Im using server telemetry channel.... folder is being created in the local disk but no logs are written to into the folder... can i know y is it not processed @PeterBons

Comment: Is it possible to post offline data using server telemetry channel or some other technique??? Can u plz give information about it??? @PeterBons

Comment: @IvanYang I worked it out, there is a known issue that prevents it from working.

Comment: @sahithiyarrabothula see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it depends on the situation.

## Scenario 1

If you are dealing with an application that can *sometimes* loose its netwerk connectivity then you can use the `ServerTelemetryChannel`.

## Scenario 2

If you want to store the telemetry offline in a central place and have a seperate process send the telemetry to Application Insigths, then no, there is no out-of-the box solution for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721396/can-application-insights-be-used-off-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well.

Now, for the first scenario this will work:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

namespace OfflineApplicationInsights
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var upc = new UsingPersistenceChannel();
            upc.Log("Test1");
            upc.Log("Test2");
            upc.Log("Test3");
            upc.Log("Test4");

            Console.ReadLine();

            upc.Flush();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    public class UsingPersistenceChannel
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _client;

        public UsingPersistenceChannel()
        {
            var config = new TelemetryConfiguration("[your key here]");
            var telemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel
            {
                StorageFolder = @"C:\Temp\ai-offline",
                DeveloperMode = false,
                MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity = 1
            };

            config.TelemetryChannel = telemetryChannel;
            telemetryChannel.Initialize(config);

            _client = new TelemetryClient(config)
            {
                InstrumentationKey = "[your key here]"
            };
        }

        public void Log(string msg)
        {
            _client.TrackTrace(msg);
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            _client.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

But, there is [a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/796) that prevents this from working sometimes. For me, it only works if I disable(!) all network adapters using the Windows configuration panel via Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

If you would to disable your network and run this program you will see some files appearing in the specified folder. Restore the network and run the application again and you will notice that the files will disappear because they are picked up by the program and send once netwerk activity is detected. At least this is how I tested it.

Comment: tq so much it helped me a lot :)

Comment: @sahithiyarrabothula well, for me it was the only way I got it working. If you read the bug report I linked to in my answer you can find some more details. It is planned to be fixed in the next release

Comment: Why first click is not collected @Peter Bons

Comment: I do not know. What do you mean with first click?

Comment: the first click on  pageview is not been tracked... @Peter Bons