# Azure log ingestion TimeGenerated problem

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have an Azure Log Analytics workspace and inside it I created a custom table to ingest some of my logs.
I used these two guides for it (mainly the first one):

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-portal
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-api

In my logs I have a field:

```
"Time": "2023-02-07 11:15:23.926060"
```

Using DCR, I create a field `TimeGenerated` like this:

```
source
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(Time)
| project-away Time
```

Everything works fine, I manage to ingest my data and query it with KQL.
The problem is that I can't ingest data with some older timestamp. If timestamp is current time or close to it, it works fine.
If my timestamp, let's say from two days ago, it overwrites it with current time.

Example of the log I send:

```
{
    "Time": "2023-02-05 11:15:23.926060",
    "Source": "VM03",
    "Status": 1
}
```

The log I receive:

```
{
    "TimeGenerated": "2023-02-07 19:35:23.926060",
    "Source": "VM03",
    "Status": 1
}
```

Can you tell why is it happening, why can't I ingest logs from several days ago and how to fix. The guides I used do not mention any of the sort at all, regrettably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hit this limit once before, a long long time ago. [Asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417543/azure-application-insight-custom-data-not-recorded-when-timestamp-or-starttime) and got a response frome someone working on Application Insights and the response was that only data not older than 48h is ingested.

Nowadays AFAIK the same applies to Log Analytics, I am not sure the same limit of 48 hours stills stands but I think it is fair to assume some limit is still enforced and there is no way around it.

Back in the time I took my loss and worked with recent data only.

Comment: Seems like you are right about 48 hours. Gonna work with recent data as well, oh well.

Comment: It's (annoyingly) still 48 hours. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-standard-columns, "The TimeGenerated value cannot be older than 2 days before received time or more than a day in the future. If in some situation, the value is older than 2 days or more than a day in the future, it would be replaced with the actual received time."

Answer (score 0):

A feature is planned by MS for Q1 2004 to also store the original/incoming TimeGenerated value.
Until that time we have an ingestion time DCR on some tables

```
source | extend TimeGenerated_CF = TimeGenerated
```